# Google Chart- Arraylist as data source

Tags: java, jsp, google-visualization

Team,

I have a set of data available in java arraylist . It holds the data  Student name, start year, end year. I split it as group of three and use in my report. Now I want to create a bar chart or gantt chart using same data in array list. Am using Google charts. I  understand that this data needs to be copied into data table which is used by the google charts as its data source. I don't want to transform using JSON and all. Need a simple and clean solution to push these data into the data table.

i switched to  Timeline chart as shown below. But the values on the x axis are not coming as requested. i.e year and month

```
 ArrayList myData holds value like this
[TASK1, 10-01-2018, 20-02-2018, TASk2, 11-02-2018, 21-03-2018, TASK3, 15-03-2018, 19-04-2018]

   function drawChart() {

      var task;var start;var end;




  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     data.addColumn('string','task');         
     data.addColumn('date','start');
      data.addColumn('date','end')

    while (loopvar<totrowcount   )

                 task ='<%=myData .get(loopvar).toString()%>';  
                 start = new Date(<%= myData .get(loopvar+1).toString()%>);
                 end = new Date(<%= myData .get(loopvar+2).toString()%>);
                 if(start<end)
                 data.addRow([task,start,end]);



     <%     
    loopvar=loopvar+4;   
        }
     %>



 var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline
```

Please find the image of the chart generated as New date function gives the time in seconds it is shown in x axis.[image]
i switched to  Timeline chart as shown below. But the values on the x axis are not coming as requested. i.e year and month

Mandan

Comment: it would be easier to answer if you could share some code, how does the data make it to the client / javascript?

Comment: Yes I will add more information

Comment: This is my code. I switched to timeline charts.

Comment: try changing the format of the date values from `DD-MM-YYYY` to `MM/DD/YYYY`...